# Python: ¿Por que no se declara mi variable?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un "lenguaje de programacion" por diversion y aprendizaje, y quiero que hayan 3 variables que vas a poder declarar, modificar, leer y mas; Pero cuando detecta una linea de codigo que deberia establecer la variable con el valor escrito por el usuario, no pasa nada, si por ejemplo luego de eso coloco un comando para leer la variable, aparece en blanco y no dice nada, este es el codigo y en el codigo se explica donde esta el error:

```
import datetime
from time import strftime
import os
import time
import random
import sys

def end():
    print("--- END EXECUTION ---")
    sys.exit()

# Aca declaro las variables. IMPORTANTE DECIR QUE LAS DEJE EN STR VACIAS
var1 = ""
var2 = ""
var3 = ""

f = open("primitive/code.nxt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    if (lines == []):
        print("--- END EXECUTION FORCED >> EMPTY SCRIPT ---")
    elif ("!" in line): #* Comment
        line = line[:99999999999999999999]
    elif ("Print > " in line):
        line = line[8:].strip()
        print(line)
    elif ("Entry >> " in line):
        line = line[9:].strip()
        input(line)
    elif ("Off > " in line):
        line = line[5:].strip()
        try:
            time.sleep(int(line))
        except:
            try:
                time.sleep(float(line))
            except:
                end()
    elif ("Var1 = Entry >> " in line): # ACA ESTA EL ERROR !!
        line = line[15:].strip() # Primero, quito todo lo de "Var1 = Entry >> " para solo dejar el mensaje del input
        var1 = input(str(line)) # Luego, hago que la variable sea igual a lo que el usuario introduzca. Muy bien, parece que funciono, pero si vamos a "Read > Var1" La salida es ""
    elif ("Read > Var1" in line):
            print(str(var1)) # Aqui esta, simplemente sale ""
    elif ("Read > Var2" in line):
            print(var2)
    elif ("Read > Var3" in line):
            print(var3)
    elif ("Random > Number > " in line):
        # Random.Number > 0, 10
        line = line[15:].strip()
        n1 = line[:1].strip()
        n2 = line[2:].strip()
        print(random.randint(int(n1), int(n2)))
    elif ("Time > Now" in line):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
    elif ("Time > Hour" in line):
        print(strftime("%H:%M"))
    elif ("Time > Zone" in line):
        print(strftime("%Z"))
    elif ("Time > Date" in line):
        print(strftime("%A") + " " + strftime("%d") + " " + strftime("%h"))
    elif ("END>" in line):
        end()

#! End of the script
end()
```

Entonces... ¿Porque el cambio a la variable "no se aplica" o directamente no funciona? Cualquier duda sobre algo mas avisen por los comentarios

AVISO: El codigo del archivo de texto donde escribi el codigo dice esto:

Codigo:

```
Print > Hola usuario
Var1 = Entry >> Introduce tu nombre:
Print > Te llamas...
Read > Var1
```

Esta es la salida:
[image: Esta es la salida]

Y como se ve, luego del "Te llamas..." no aparece nada, entonces asumo que no se declaro la variable por algun motivo y sigue igual que antes, sigue estando asi: ""

¿Por que pasa esto? ¿Como lo arreglo?

Saludos Comunidad de Stack Overflow! :D

Comment: Se te ha olvidado poner la asignación: En el bloque `elif ("Entry >> " in line):`, añade como última línea `var1 = input(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una solución más sencilla para manejar las variables, como demostraremos implementando este mini-lenguaje que soporta sólo estas operaciones:

```
var = valor
print [var]
fin
```

La primera asigna valor a una variable, y la segunda imprime la variable opcional (o todas las variables definidas hasta el momento).

El valor puede ser cualquiera; simplemente tomamos todo lo que viene después del signo "=".

`fin` se usa para terminar la ejecución.

Usaremos un diccionario para guardar las variables. La llave será el nombre de la variable, y su valor lo que se ingrese, tal cual, sin transformación.

Con esta solución no tenemos restricciones respecto a la cantidad de variables, sus nombres o sus contenidos.

```
variables = {}

instruccion = ""
while instruccion != "fin":
    instruccion = input(">")

    if instruccion.startswith("print"):
        if len(instruccion) > len("print"):
            _, variable = instruccion.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
            if variable in variables:
                print(variables[variable])
            else:
                print(f"Error. {variable} no existe")
        else:
            print(variables)
    elif "=" in instruccion:
        variable, valor = instruccion.split("=",maxsplit=1)
        variables[variable] = valor
    elif instruccion == "fin":
        break
    else:
        print("Error.")
```

produce:

```
>a=5
>b=6
>print a
5
>print b
6
>print c
Error. c no existe
>list
Error.
>print
{'a': '5', 'b': '6'}
>fin

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: No entiendo ¿Cual es la diferencia entre lo que escribi yo y lo que hiciste tu?